# What is faster / better? More SQL-Select statements or multiple detailed sql commands?

Tags: mysql, node.js, performance

i work on a project with node.js and a mysql database.
i have a connection between them with the npm modul mysql. 
Now my question:
is it better to send a SQL command and sort the data in node.js or multiple detailed sql commands?
what is faster / more performant?

Thanks.

Comment: Try it both ways and benchmark it. This is too vague to answer.

Comment: I think an important consideration is if your data requirements change, how much effort is it to rework the complex queries

Comment: I guess  it depends on your query. Generally, the database is good for data manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact SQL queries, I would say that database operations are faster compared to your own implementation. Many smart people have worked to assure performance, accuracy, atomicity, concurrency etc. of the Mysql engine.

Even if you can gain marginal improvements in some aspect with your own code, it is unlikely that you will be able to justify the investment.